# Print Format in arduino

Tags: printing, arduino, format, sensors, content-length

```
// defines pins numbers
const int trigPin = 9;
const int echoPin = 10;

// defines variables
long duration;
int distance;  // float distance ;

void setup() {
pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication
}

void loop() {
// Clears the trigPin
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);

// Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

// Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

// Calculating the distance
distance= duration*0.034/2;

// Prints the distance on the Serial Monitor
Serial.println(distance);
}
```

I want to get

`1` as `01` for int

`2.54` as `02.54` for float

in my arduino Serial Monitor. Please how do I go about it. My sensor sends out the value without placing the zero in front of it, which is normal. How can I edit the print format.
Thank you all

Comment: Maybe this? https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/34929/format-integer-in-arduino Or perhaps this https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=43562.0

Answer (score 0):

The  easiest way is simply:

```
if (distance < 10) Serial.write('0'); Serial.println(distance);
```

*Does not care about negative ints, which might be ok for a distance*